# .htaccess - help with a rewrite rule for ssl

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

So I've got a website and an SSL certificate. Everything is set up and working, however, both `http://example.com/checkout` and `https://example.com/checkout` work. I'm hoping there's a way to write a rule where anything going to /checkout is rerouted to https.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^checkout$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```